# count the number of times 0 occurs

Tags: flowchart

I am trying to draw the flowchart for this question and stuck.
**Given a list A of n numbers, count the number of times 0 occurs in the list**.It might be an easy question but I am a beginner and don't have much idea about most questions. Please help me draw that!

Comment: do you expect a psuedo code as ans or do you want a complete flowchart?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822. We don't do work requests here - we **answer a question**, which means first you must have a *specific idea of what you don't know yet* in order to solve the problem. "Please help me" is [not a question, and not answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236); and telling us that you are a beginner is [not helpful, and only a distraction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721). Also: while such a question is on topic here, please also consider [cs.se].

Comment: For example: what do you imagine are the logical steps in order to solve the problem? If you actually have a list of numbers, **how** do you count them? (Hint: how many of the numbers do you have to consider in order to solve the problem? When you consider one of the numbers, what do you need to find out about it? Depending on what you find out, what action should you take? Can you handle all the numbers at once, or should you think about them one at a time? Do they have some kind of order?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the list A and for each value, check if the value is equal to zero. If it is, add 1 to a running total.

In pseudo code:

```
total = 0
listA = [1, 5, 0, 2, 0, ...]
for i = 0 to len(listA):
    if listA[i] == 0:
        total = total + 1
    next i
```